# Method works in applicationDidFinishLaunching, but not in another method (in the same file)!

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm making an app that needs to create a directory to download some files. When I call

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:
[[self.searchURL theDownloadLocation] stringByStandardizingPath]
withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```

within

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

it works fine. I have a button that is supposed to commence the download. I've laid it out in the xib file and it works to do anything else, so I know the button works. Again, the directory is created with no issue if I call the `NSFileManager` method within `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, but not within the other method called when I press the button. It crashes with an `(lldb)` message.

The parameters being passed are exactly the same, I've even `NSLog`ged the `[[self.searchURL theDownloadLocation] stringByStandardizingPath]` in the button method, and it's definitely an `NSString`, so it logs when I press the button. What am I missing?

I sometimes get an error message:

```
2013-02-12 19:33:04.404 dArt[2351:303] -[NSISRestrictedToNonNegativeVariableToBeMinimized
stringByStandardizingPath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100528ba0
2013-02-12 19:33:04.405 dArt[2351:303] -[NSISRestrictedToNonNegativeVariableToBeMinimized
stringByStandardizingPath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100528ba0
```

```
2013-02-12 19:33:04.408 dArt[2351:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff862c40a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d4e53f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8635a6ea -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff862b25ce ___forwarding___ + 414
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff862b23b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   dArt                                0x000000010000248d -[AppDelegate searchTheArt:] + 141
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a91ea59 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 342
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a91e8b7 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 85
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a91e7eb -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 138
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a91ccd3 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1855
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a91c521 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 504
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a91bc9c -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 820
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a91360e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6853
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a90f744 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5761
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a8252fa -[NSApplication run] + 636
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7c9cb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
    16  dArt                                0x00000001000016b2 main + 34
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8b36b7e1 start + 0
)
```

Comment: Nothing about your problem makes much sense. You create a directory when starting up, yet you attempt to do it again when some button is pushed? What kind of object is `searchURL` that accepts a message like you've shown? Most important of all, what's your error message? It'd really be illuminating if you'd provide it.

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint at your button tap handler to confirm that it is indeed firing?

Comment: @trudyscousin No, it's only supposed to happen when the button is pressed, but I moved it to the main method to debug it. It works there. searchURL is an ordinary NSObject class that I created. The error message is `lldb`, like I said, it just crashes with that message.

Comment: @trudyscousin I added the error message to the main question. Sometimes, it gives that message, other times, it just crashes and says `(lldb)`.

Comment: Alright, here's some more info. I moved the `theDownloadLocation` property out of SearchURL.h and into AppDelegate.h, as well as changing all instances of `[self.searchURL setTheDownloadLocation]` to `[self setTheDownloadLocation]`. Then, I logged theDownloadLocation from [self theDownloadLocation], rather than [self.searchURL theDownloadLocation]. Logging it from searchURL would crash the app. Logging it from AppDelegate.h does not. It prints this instead: `<CGContext 0x101c39ef0>`

Comment: Wow, I just built it again, changing nothing, now this is the output: `<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x101b18990 V:[NSTextField:0x10011d290(22)] Hug:750 CompressionResistance:750>`

I build it a third time, changing nothing and this is the output: `2013-02-12 20:17:59.588 dArt[8783:303] NSCTFontDescriptor <0x101c09f50> = {
    NSFontNameAttribute = "LucidaGrande-Bold";
}`

Each time I click the button, the output is the same, *until I build it again*, but without changing anything else. Literally, seconds between builds, absolutely no change.

Comment: The fourth build just resulted in an `(lldb)` crash!

Comment: It is going to be had for anyone to help you with this unless you post more of your code. Don't be shy and copy paste your classes in here.

Comment: Alright, but just for the record, I am new to GUI programming, as well as Objective-C. I literally just went over the "Your First Mac App" and tried to make this app, learning everything as I go along.

Comment: I can't get the code formatting to work, so I'll just give you a link to the whole Xcode project.

http://cl.ly/Mqzb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question has been answered elsewhere. I just needed to add the `(copy)` qualifier to `theDownloadLocation` property.

Like `@property (copy) NSString *theDownloadLocation;`

Comment: I presume that's an `NSString *`?

Comment: Still, this doesn't seem like it should have fixed the problem. I'm guessing there's some kind of memory access problem – scribbling on memory, or keeping around an instance of a deallocated method. Instead I'd suggest debugging with NSZombie.

Comment: Well, it definitely fixed it. I asked another board for help, Cocoa developer board. A guy took one look at it and told me to change that `assign` to `copy`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you had `assign`. It would probably work with `retain` too.

Comment: You should almost never use `assign` with object types.

Comment: Yeah, I only went over "Your First Mac App" before using the language, and Apple uses assign on the properties, so I assumed that the assign meant to "assign" the property to the object.